# c# How to put value outside of for looping?

Tags: c#

I am starting to learn C#. I want to know how to put a value outside of a `for` loop like this:

```
int firstByte;
if (bytes == 1)
{                          
    for (int j = 0; j < bytes; j++)
    {
        firstByte = comBuffer[j];
        if (firstByte == 0x06)
        {
            checkStatus = 2;
        }
   }
}
```

`bytes` is the length of `comBuffer`, and `comBuffer`'s value is `[0x01,0x06]`. Is that a way to put the `if(firstbyte == 0x06)` outside of the `for` loop?. I want to put it outside of the `for` loop because I want add another `if-else` using `if(firstbyte)` outside of the loop.

My expectation is some like this:

```
int firstByte;
if (bytes == 1)
{                          
    for (int j = 0; j < bytes; j++)
    {
        firstByte = comBuffer[j];
        if (firstByte == 0x06)
        {
            checkStatus = 2;
        }
   }
}

if(firstByte == 0x06)
{ 
   string status = "OK";
}
```

When i try it, the program shows a warning message `"unasigned value ....."`.
Any solution or suggestion?

Comment: what is the purpose of your `if` which is after the first `if` block?

Comment: can you give any default value at the time of declaration like `int firstByte =  0`. See if this solves an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assign default value at the time of declaration

```
   int firstByte = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's first understand what the problem is.

```
int firstByte;
**if (bytes == 1)**
{                          
for (int j = 0; j < bytes; j++)
{
    firstByte = comBuffer[j];
    if (firstByte == 0x06)
    {
        checkStatus = 2;
    }
}
}

if(firstByte == 0x06)
{ 
 string status = "OK";
}
```

firstByte is assigned a value only if bytes is 1, so there is this possibility of firstByte not being assigned anything and being checked in the outside if condition. You can easily avoid this problem by assigning firstByte a value like 0 or something that doesnt interfere with your logic.

```
int firtByte = 0;
```

will solve your problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
int firstByte;
```

Your firstByte must have some value when assigning it.
for example:

```
int firstByte = 1;
```

Oherwise it cant be used with if because it has not the value to compare in statement.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a variable in your code without initializing it with a value, the compiler will throw an error if you try to access that variable unless your code guarantees that it will be assigned a value before it is accessed. In your example, you declare `int firstByte;` without assigning it a value. It doesn't receive a value until `firstByte = comBuffer[j];`, which is inside an if-block and a for-loop, either of which could conceivably skip the execution of their bodies without reaching that line of code.

Initializing firstByte with a value (such as `int firstValue = -1;`) will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible in two ways,

1. Make int firstByte as global
2. Assign a default value for `firstByte`.

Something like the following:

```
int firstByte=0;
```

Or

```
int firstByte=0X64;
```

Or some other values as per your requirements.

**Why compiler is showing such message :** Their may be chances for the condition `bytes==1` evaluates to false, or the looping skip the loop. in such cases there is no assigned value for `firstByte` when you try to check it outside those conditions. Hence it shows the warning to make it perfect

Answer (score -1):

I usually use nullables in this case:

```
int? firstByte = null;
```